# List of apps installed from playstore for particular email address

Tags: android, google-play

I want to create an app that can list all installed app that are downloaded using particular email address.

For E.g

testplaylist@gmail.com is registered in my phone and I have installed 3 apps

1. Angry bird
2. Mighty Text
3. SMS pro

I would like to get this list of app on opening my app? I am not sure where to start with? Something similar to what https://play.google.com/apps - has after you login.

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Is this possible?

Hopefully not, unless you wish to get arrested for stealing users' Google account passwords. There certainly is no public API anywhere for you to peek at what other people have installed, for obvious privacy and security reasons.